# Extract functions from class file

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3, recursion

I am working on a regular expression to extract functions from an AS3 class file, in Javascript. 
But I have an issue with the function who have inner brackets in it (like an inner if or whatever).

I see that I could do that recursively with a `(?<body>{(?:[^{}]+|(?-1))*+})` but this is not working on Javascript because the recursion `(?-1)` isn't supported.

I would like to know if someone could help me figure another solution. 
Here is me regex101 test = https://regex101.com/r/eE6mX3/1

```
\((?:[^)(]+|\((?:[^)(]+|\([^)(]*\))*\))*\)
```

Thanks for everyone who can help me.

Comment: You can't parse JavaScript with just a single regular expression. Attempts to do so just waste your time. Use a parser. If you look around, you can find several.

Comment: What you want to use can be achieved with [`balanced-match`](https://github.com/juliangruber/balanced-match) or  [`XRegExp.matchRecursive`](http://xregexp.com/api/#matchRecursive). However, it will only work in case you have no string literals/comments with unbalanced `{` and `}` inside them.

Comment: Yeah I saw the balanced-match and matchRecursive but It will not work for me. :(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you give a parser you think is good enough ?

Comment: @user2917569: I haven't had to look for one for AS3. The last time I needed a JavaScript parser, I used Esprima.

Comment: Try also using [**`String functions`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) to extract code text. Show an **example AS3 function**, show what result you get from your code effort and explain the **expected result**. Show **testable code** (even not working) if you want help to fix it.

Comment: This is a pretty odd question as a generalized problem. AS3 is not generally compatible with JS/DOM, so "extracting functions" doesn't really make sense. Do you have a specific AS3 class you are trying to convert to JS? Are you just trying to extract the names, or the function body as well? Do you want the extracted function to do anything in JS? (If so, you have a lot more issues than just parsing out the methods of a class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Warning! You read on at your own risk! Really ugly regex ahead!!!**

(This is the answer I originally started on, and it shouldn't be taken to serious. But there's a lot of work behind it, so I publish it anyway. My other answer should be what you want.)

---

Now... This is possible to a certain extent - it can be done if the number of levels of nesting is limited.

(I should mention that I have no experience with AS3, and can't quite relate your example at regex101 with what I've googled.)

Assuming it's the body of a *normal* JS function you wan't to grab this solution should (could) do it for you.

---

**Nesting**

Matching an inner scope is easily done with `{[^{}]*}`. This matches two surrounding braces and anything between them (`[^{}]*` is a negated character class matching any character **but** `{` and `}` - the `*` means *any number of times*). Live example:

```js
var re = /{[^{}]*}/,
    str = 'one { two { three { four { five } six } seven } eight } nine';
    
    document.write(str.match( re ));
```

Now if we need to match a nested level, this can easily be done by simply adding the level to the regex like `{[^{}]*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*}`. Live example:

```js
var re = /{[^{}]*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*}/,
    str = 'one { two { three { four { five } six } seven } eight } nine';
    
    document.write(str.match( re ));
```

Even four levels - no problem: `{[^{}]*{[^{}]*{[^{}]*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*}[^{}]*}[^{}]*}`. Live example:

```js
var re = /{[^{}]*{[^{}]*{[^{}]*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*}[^{}]*}[^{}]*}/,
    str = 'one { two { three { four { five } six } seven } eight } nine';
    
    document.write(str.match( re ));
```

You could go even further, of course, but it's *beginning*(?) to look nasty.

---

**Strings and comments**

Now you may ask yourself - "What about strings and comments?" (as mentioned by Wiktor). Well, there's a solution for it .

If we take the string `{one /* two } */ three ' { four }' "} five {" } // {six}` (representing a JS code line with comments) we can easily match the separate *parts* by them self.

- `'(?:\\'|[^'])*'` Matches a single-quoted string (allowing escaped single quotes).
- `"(?:\\"|[^"])*"` Matches a double-quoted string (allowing escaped double quotes).
- `\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/` Matches a `/* abc */` style comment (possibly multi line).
- `\/\/.*` Matches a `// abc` (end of line) style comment

Joining these into alternations matches all these - illustrated here:

```js
var re = /'(?:\\'|[^'])*'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*/g,
    str = '{one /* two } */ three \'{ four }\' "} five {" } // {six}';
    
    document.write(str.match( re ).join('<br/>'));
```

First there's the comment `/* two } */`, followed by the strings `' { four }'` 
 and `"} five {"`, and finally the `// {six}` comment.

---

**Putting it all together**

Starting by matching the string/comment parts, we can avoid having the *unwanted* braces included in our search for matched pairs. We'll also include a character class consisting of all *legal* Javascript characters (white-space, word characters, operators, punctuations and so on) in the alternation.

Then here's what we need to get the inner scope:

```
{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*}
```

Live example:

```js
var re = /{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*}/,
    code = '// Example code\nfunction(a,b,c) {\n\t// Return sum of all arguments\n\treturn a+b+c;\n\t// Ignore this: }\n}\n';
    
document.write('<span style="background-color:lightblue;">ORIGINAL CODE:<br/></span>');
document.write(code.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));

document.write('<span style="background-color:lightblue;">INNER SCOPE:<br/></span>');
document.write(code.match(re)[0].replace(/\n/g, '<br/>'));
```

Combining this with the nest-logic explained above we'll have (a **really** complex) regex that should do the trick, with the previously stated limitations. (Having to many levels of nesting may cause a time out).

```
(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*([^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*([^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*([^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?
```

(**OMG!!!** Ive created a monster!)

```js
var re = /{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*(?:{(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*})?(?:(?:'(?:\\'|[^'])*?'|"(?:\\"|[^"])*?"|\/\*(?:[^*]*)*?\*\/|\/\/.*)|[\s\w-+\/*.=,();|&[\]:])*}/g,
    unnecessary_complex_code = "var str='123';\n\nfunction /* 123 * 4 * / */ test(\n// qwe\nparam // qwe\n, rapam\n) // \n{\n\ndocument /* qwe*/ . // write\nwrite ( /*\ntest\n*/ test(123) // );\n);\n\n if(param===rapam) {\n  if( false ) {\n   // Another nested level\n   var another_level = {\n    test: { result: true  }\n   };\n  }\n  return // 'FALSE';\n   'TRUE;\n } else return /* 'TRUE';\n */ 'FALSE'\n;\n  /*\n}\n*/\n}\n";
    
    console.log('Code used:');
    console.log(unnecessary_complex_code);
    console.log('Result:');
    console.log(unnecessary_complex_code.match(re));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier than you think, and doesn't require any regex **or** parsing whatsoever ;)

It's easier to show an example before explaining it:

```js
// This is an example of how a function may look

function Demo(first, second, third) {
  // Concatenate the first and second if third is undefined
  if(!third) { // This is to illustrate that a { doesn't cause any problem
    return first + ' - ' + second;
  }
  if(third==='first') { /*
    No problem with } this either
    */ return first;
  }
  if(third==='second') {
    return second;
  }
  else {
    if(third==='first and second') {
      return first + ' and ' + second;
    }
  }
}

// Now show what the function returns when invoked
console.log('The function returns:\n' + Demo('one', 'two'));

// And now - the magic: show the function definition
console.log('The function definition is:\n' + Demo);
```

```css
span.result {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
span.definition {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

Accessing a function without `()` will return the function definition and not the result of the function.